# Utilizar solo la parte entera del valor de una variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

Con este código (teniendo algún borrador en Gmail)

```
    function enviarDeDRAFTS(){
   numero_borradores = GmailApp.getDrafts().length; Logger.log(numero_borradores);
   for (i=0;i<numero_borradores;i++){     
     var borrador = GmailApp.getDrafts()[i];
     Logger.log(borrador)
     borrador.send;
   }
   }
```

El valor que devuelve la variable es un número seguido de .0 ( con un decimal).
¿Cómo puedo hacer para eliminar la parte .0 (decimal) del valor de la variable?

Lo que quiero es que esta función detecte el número de borradores que hay y los envíe.

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza

```
Logger.log(numero_borradores);
```

por

```
Logger.log(Math.floor(numero_borradores));
```

Recursos

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor